# filtering in a dictionary based on the index in python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have a multi-dictionary as below:

```
 arcs, capacity = multidict({
                            ('Detroit', 'Boston'):   100,
                            ('Detroit', 'New York'):  80,
                            ('Detroit', 'Seattle'):  120,
                            ('Denver',  'Boston'):   120,
                            ('Denver',  'New York'): 120,
                            ('Denver',  'Seattle'):  120 })
```

Could you please tell me how can I select rows which has 'Denver' in their index?

Comment: I think you have enough rep to know how to formulate a proper question with a [mcve]. Please revise that and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Where is `multidict` from?

Comment: @ Patrick Haugh: Could you please tell me what do you mean? Sorry, I'm a beginner in python and don't know may stuff.

Comment: `multidict` is not a standard part of Python.  Where is it from?  without knowing how it's structured, there's not a whole lot of specific advice we can give.

Comment: @ Patrick Haugh: Actually, I have seen it in the examples of python and and optimization software interface. I simply copied it here since it is very much like what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how `multidict` differs from `dict`, but you could use something like:

```
{k:v for k, v in d if 'Denver' in k}
```